# How to utilise all the cores of CPU and GPU in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am new in Keras and TensorFlow. I prepared a very small convolution neural network in keras with TensorFlow as backend.

```
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)

        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)

        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
            input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

My machine has external GPU. When I am training the model, it's utilizing the GPU but not CPU cores. How can I make it enable to use all the cores of CPU as well as GPU?

Comment: If its using the GPU, then it does not need to use all CPU cores. The GPU is way faster than the CPU.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yeah, GPU is obviously faster than CPU but I guess if I would be able to use all the cores of CPU, it would be little bit faster than GPU.

Comment: No, that's not the case with current CPUs.

Comment: sorry for the previous comment, that was typo. Actually I meant, if I would be able to use both CPU and GPU, it will be bit faster than GPU alone.

Comment: That is also not necessarily the case, all the parallel code is already running on the GPU, and the sequential parts on the CPU. While training the CPU is just moving data around and applying updates, more cores won't help much.

Comment: this is informative, thanks